# Working with tuples in python?

Tags: python

I have three lists in python. Let's say :

```
list_a
list_b
list_c
```

Now I am calling a method which also return a list and save into the above lists.
For example:

```
list_a = get_value(1)
list_b = get_value(2)
list_c = get_value(3)
```

I think the way I choose to call a same methods with different parameters are not a good option. Would it be possible for us to call these methods within one line?

I am beginner in Python, but what about the tuple option?

Comment: Note that the line `list_a = get_value(1)` does not "save the return value into the above list".  You would need to use `list_a[:] = get_value(1)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of lists?

```
ll = [get_value(x) for x in (1, 2, 3)]
```

or with your three lists:

```
list_a, list_b, list_c = [get_value(x) for x in (1, 2, 3)]
```

taking into account, that `get_value` cannot be modified and returns just the single list.

Another possibility would be a dictionary.

```
params = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
result = {k:get_value(v) for k,v in params.iteritems()}
# result == {'a': get_value(1), 'b': get_value(2), 'c': get_value(3)}
```

Comment: +1 nice (and I was just going to suggest the unpacking to the 3 variables)

Comment: you could even use a generator for this, not sure if it would actually be more efficient for large sets of data.

Answer (score 3):

If your function was set up correctly (ie modified to return the same number of lists as you send in parameters) you could have a call that looked like this:

```
 list_a, list_b, list_c = get_value(1, 2, 3)
```

where `get_value()` would return a tuple of 3 values.

Is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
list_a, list_b, list_c = map(get_value, (1,2,3))
```